# iOS: verify if a point is inside a rect

Tags: ios, uiview, collision-detection, cgrect, cgpoint

Is there a way to verify if a `CGPoint` is inside a specific `CGRect`?

An example would be:
I'm dragging a `UIImageView` and I want to verify if its central point `CGPoint` is inside another `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

#### Swift 4

```
let view = ...
let point = ...
view.bounds.contains(point)
```

#### Objective-C

Use [`CGRectContainsPoint()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456316-cgrectcontainspoint?language=occ):

`bool CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point);`

**Parameters**

- `rect`     The rectangle to examine.
- `point`    The point to examine.
  Return Value
  true if the rectangle is not null or empty and the point is located within the rectangle; otherwise, false.

A point is considered inside the rectangle if its coordinates lie inside the rectangle or on the minimum X or minimum Y edge.

Comment: The missing link ;) https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Is is possible to check CGPoint is in line context (CGContext)?

Comment: in Swift 3.0 use like: rect = frame of a view, and then isContain = rect.contains(point)

Answer (score 45):

In Swift that would look like this:

```
let point = CGPointMake(20,20)
let someFrame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)
let isPointInFrame = CGRectContainsPoint(someFrame, point)
```

Swift 3 version:

```
let point = CGPointMake(20,20)
let someFrame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)
let isPointInFrame = someFrame.contains(point)
```

[Link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains) . Please remember to check containment if both are in the same coordinate system if not then conversions are required ([some example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465817/3151066))

Answer (score 15):

In swift you can do it like this:

```
let isPointInFrame = frame.contains(point)
```

"frame" is a CGRect and "point" is a CGPoint

Answer (score 12):

UIView's pointInside:withEvent: could be a good solution.
Will return a boolean value indicating wether or not the given CGPoint is in the UIView instance you are using.
Example:

```
UIView *aView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
CGPoint aPoint = CGPointMake(5,5);
BOOL isPointInsideView = [aView pointInside:aPoint withEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

In objective c you can use **CGRectContainsPoint(yourview.frame, touchpoint)**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchpoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if( CGRectContainsPoint(yourview.frame, touchpoint) ) {

}else{

}}
```

In swift 3 **yourview.frame.contains(touchpoint)**

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let touchpoint:CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
    if wheel.frame.contains(touchpoint)  {

    }else{

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is so simple,you can use following method to do this kind of work:-

```
-(BOOL)isPoint:(CGPoint)point insideOfRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(rect,point))
        return  YES;// inside
    else
        return  NO;// outside
}
```

In your case,you can pass **imagView.center** as point and another **imagView.frame** as rect in about method.

You can also use this method in bellow **UITouch** Method :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to learn how to code with Swift and was trying to solve this too, this is what I came up with on Swift's playground:

```
// Code
var x = 1
var y = 2
var lowX = 1
var lowY = 1
var highX = 3
var highY = 3


if (x, y) >= (lowX, lowY) && (x, y) <= (highX, highY ) {
    print("inside")
} else {
    print("not inside")
}
```

It prints *inside*

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
            UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(vwTable.frame.origin.x, 
            vwTable.frame.origin.y, vwTable.frame.size.width, 
            vwTable.frame.size.height);
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect1,touchLocation))
            NSLog(@"Inside");
            else
            NSLog(@"Outside");
    }
```