# Understand convertRect:toView:, convertRect:FromView:, convertPoint:toView: and convertPoint:fromView: methods

Tags: ios, layout, uiview

I'm trying to understand the functionalities of these methods. Could you provide me with a simple use case to understand their semantics?

From the documentation, for example, `convertPoint:fromView:` method is described as follows:

> Converts a point from the coordinate system of a given view to that of the receiver.

What does the **coordinate system** mean? What about the **receiver**?

For example, does it make sense using `convertPoint:fromView:` like the following?

```
CGPoint p = [view1 convertPoint:view1.center fromView:view1];
```

Using NSLog utility, I've verified that `p` value coincides with `view1`'s center.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** For those interested, I've created a simple code snippet to understand these methods.

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 200)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
NSLog(@"view1 frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view1.frame));        
NSLog(@"view1 center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(view1.center));   
    
CGPoint originInWindowCoordinates = [self.window convertPoint:view1.bounds.origin fromView:view1];        
NSLog(@"convertPoint:fromView: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(originInWindowCoordinates));
    
CGPoint originInView1Coordinates = [self.window convertPoint:view1.frame.origin toView:view1];        
NSLog(@"convertPoint:toView: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(originInView1Coordinates));
```

In both cases `self.window` is the receiver. But there is a difference. In the first case the `convertPoint` parameter is expressed in `view1` coordinates. The output is the following:

> convertPoint:fromView: {100, 100}

In the second one, instead, `convertPoint` is expressed in superview (`self.window`) coordinates. The output is the following:

> convertPoint:toView: {0, 0}

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Each view has its own coordinate system - with an origin at 0,0 and a width and height. This is described in the `bounds` rectangle of the view. The `frame` of the view, however, will have its origin at the point within the bounds rectangle of its superview.

The outermost view of your view hierarchy has it's origin at 0,0 which corresponds to the top left of the screen in iOS.

If you add a subview at 20,30 to this view, then a point at 0,0 in the subview corresponds to a point at 20,30 in the superview. This conversion is what those methods are doing.

Your example above is pointless (no pun intended) since it converts a point from a view to itself, so nothing will happen. You would more commonly find out where some point of a view was in relation to its superview - to test if a view was moving off the screen, for example:

```
CGPoint originInSuperview = [superview convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:subview];
```

The "receiver" is a standard objective-c term for the object that is receiving the message (methods are also known as messages) so in my example here the receiver is `superview`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, jrturton. Very useful explanation. `convertPoint` and `convertRect` differ in the return type. `CGPoint` or `CGRect`. But what about `from` and `to`? Is there a rule of thumb that I could use? Thank you.

Comment: from when you want to convert from, to when you want to convert to?

Comment: What if superview is not the direct parent view of subview, will it still work?

Comment: @VanDuTran yes, as long as they are in the same window (which most views in an iOS app are)

Comment: Great answer.  Helped clear up a lot for me.  Any additional reading?

Comment: @jrturton Is `center` also in superView's coordinate system?

Comment: @jrturton what if the object in question is in another class

Answer (score 45):

I always find this confusing so I made a playground where you can visually explore what the `convert` function does. This is done in Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1b:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Main view
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)

        // Red view
        let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 460, height: 460))
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(redView)

        // Blue view
        let blueView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 420, height: 420))
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        redView.addSubview(blueView)

        // Orange view
        let orangeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 380, height: 380))
        orangeView.backgroundColor = .orange
        blueView.addSubview(orangeView)

        // Yellow view
        let yellowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 340, height: 100))
        yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        orangeView.addSubview(yellowView)


        // Let's try to convert now
        var resultFrame = CGRect.zero
        let randomRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)

        /*
        func convert(CGRect, from: UIView?)
        Converts a rectangle from the coordinate system of another view to that of the receiver.
        */

        // The following line converts a rectangle (randomRect) from the coordinate system of yellowView to that of self.view:
        resultFrame = view.convert(randomRect, from: yellowView)

        // Try also one of the following to get a feeling of how it works:
        // resultFrame = view.convert(randomRect, from: orangeView)
        // resultFrame = view.convert(randomRect, from: redView)
        // resultFrame = view.convert(randomRect, from: nil)

        /*
        func convert(CGRect, to: UIView?)
        Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of another view.
        */

        // The following line converts a rectangle (randomRect) from the coordinate system of yellowView to that of self.view
        resultFrame = yellowView.convert(randomRect, to: view)
        // Same as what we did above, using "from:"
        // resultFrame = view.convert(randomRect, from: yellowView)

        // Also try:
        // resultFrame = orangeView.convert(randomRect, to: view)
        // resultFrame = redView.convert(randomRect, to: view)
        // resultFrame = orangeView.convert(randomRect, to: nil)


        // Add an overlay with the calculated frame to self.view
        let overlay = UIView(frame: resultFrame)
        overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.9)
        overlay.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        overlay.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        view.addSubview(overlay)
    }
}

var ctrl = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ctrl.view
```

Remember to show the Assistant Editor (<kbd>⎇</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>) in order to see the views, it should look like this:

[image]

Feel free to contribute more examples here or in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/phi161/e4d8c56b89ab4f7692df6c20ce89e461).

Comment: Great overview. However I think those `self.view` are redundant, simple use `view` if `self` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @JakubTruhlář, I just removed `self`

Answer (score 30):

Here's an explanation in plain English.

When you want to convert the rect of a subview (`aView` is a subview of `[aView superview]`) to the coordinate space of another view (`self`).

```
// So here I want to take some subview and put it in my view's coordinate space
_originalFrame = [[aView superview] convertRect: aView.frame toView: self];
```

Comment: This isn't true. It doesn't move the view, it just gives you the co-ordinates of the view in terms of another. In your case it will give you the co-ordinates of aView in terms of where they'd be in self.

Comment: Correct.  It doesn't move the view.  The method returns a CGRect.  What you choose to do with that CGRect is your business.  :-)  In the case above, it could be used to move one view to another's hierarchy while maintaining its visual position on screen.

Answer (score 15):

Every view in iOS have a coordinate system. A coordinate system is just like a graph, which has x axis(horizontal line) and y axis(vertical line). The point at which the lines interesect is called origin. A point is represented by (x, y). For example, (2, 1) means that the point is 2 pixels left, and 1 pixel down.

You can read up more about coordinate systems here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system

But what you need to know is that, in iOS, every view has it's OWN coordinate system, where the top left corner is the origin. X axis goes on increasing to the right, and y axis goes on increasing down.

For the converting points question, take this example.

There is a view, called V1, which is 100 pixels wide and 100 pixels high. Now inside that, there is another view, called V2, at (10, 10, 50, 50) which means that (10, 10) is the point in V1's coordinate system where the top left corner of V2 should be located, and (50, 50) is the width and height of V2. Now, take a point INSIDE V2's coordinate system, say (20, 20). Now, what would that point be inside V1's coordinate system? That is what the methods are for(of course you can calculate themselves, but they save you extra work). For the record, the point in V1 would be (30, 30).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you all for posting the question and your answers: It helped me get this sorted out.

My view controller has it's normal view.

Inside that view there are a number of grouping views that do little more than give their child views a clean interaction with auto layout constraints.

Inside one of those grouping views I have an Add button that presents a popover view controller where the user enters some information.

```
view
--groupingView
----addButton
```

During device rotation the view controller is alerted via the UIPopoverViewControllerDelegate call popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:

```
- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view
{
    *rect = [self.addButton convertRect:self.addbutton.bounds toView:*view];
}
```

The essential part that comes from the explanation given by the first two answers above was that the rect I needed to convert from was the ***bounds*** of the add button, not its frame.

I haven't tried this with a more complex view hierarchy, but I suspect that by using the view supplied in the method call (inView:) we get around the complications of multi-tiered leaf view kinds of ugliness.

Comment: "I needed to convert from was the bounds of the add button, not it's frame." - essentially saved me from a lot of ugly frame code to make it work. Thanks for taking the time to point this out

Answer (score 3):

I used this post to apply in my case.  Hope this will help another reader in the future.

A view can only see its immediate children and parent views.  It can't see its grand parents or its grandchildren views.

So, in my case, I have a grand parent view called `self.view`, in this `self.view` I have added subviews called `self.child1OfView`, `self.child2OfView`.  In `self.child1OfView`, I have added subviews called `self.child1OfView1`, `self.child2OfView1`.
Now if I physically move `self.child1OfView1` to an area outside the boundary of `self.child1OfView` to anther spot on `self.view`, then to calculator the new position for the `self.child1OfView1` within the `self.view:`

```
CGPoint newPoint = [self.view convertPoint:self.child1OfView1.center fromView:self.child1OfView];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see below code so you can understand that how it actually works.

```
    let scrollViewTemp = UIScrollView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: deviceWidth - 20, height: deviceHeight - 20))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollViewTemp.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    scrollViewTemp.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: 2000, height: 2000)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollViewTemp)

    let viewTemp = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150))
    viewTemp.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.addSubview(viewTemp)

    let viewSecond = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 100, y: 700, width: 300, height: 300))
    viewSecond.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(viewSecond)

    self.view.convert(viewTemp.frame, from: scrollViewTemp)
    print(viewTemp.frame)


    /*  First take one point CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10) of viewTemp frame,then give distance from viewSecond frame to this point.
     */
    let point = viewSecond.convert(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), from: viewTemp)
    //output:   (10.0, -190.0)
    print(point)

    /*  First take one point CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10) of viewSecond frame,then give distance from viewTemp frame to this point.
     */
    let point1 = viewSecond.convert(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), to: viewTemp)
    //output:  (10.0, 210.0)
    print(point1)

    /*  First take one rect CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20) of viewSecond frame,then give distance from viewTemp frame to this rect.
     */
    let rect1 = viewSecond.convert(CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20), to: viewTemp)
    //output:  (10.0, 210.0, 20.0, 20.0)
    print(rect1)

    /* First take one rect CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20) of viewTemp frame,then give distance from viewSecond frame to this rect.
     */
    let rect = viewSecond.convert(CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20), from: viewTemp)
    //output:  (10.0, -190.0, 20.0, 20.0)
    print(rect)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read the answer and understand the mechanics but I think the final example is not correct. According to the API doc, the center property of a view contains the known center point of the view in the superview’s coordinate system.

If this is the case, than I think it would not make sense to try to ask the superview to convert the center of a subview FROM the subview coordinate system because the value is not in the subview coordinate system. What would make sense is to do the opposite i.e. convert from the superview coordinate system to that of a subview...

You can do it in two ways (both should yield the same value):

```
CGPoint centerInSubview = [subview convertPoint:subview.center fromView:subview.superview];
```

or

```
CGPoint centerInSubview = [subview.superview convertPoint:subview.center toView:subview];
```

Am I way off in understanding how this should work?

Comment: My example was incorrect, I have updated the answer. As you say, the center property is already in the superview's coordinate space.

Answer (score 1):

One more important point about using these APIs. Be sure that the parent view chain is complete between the rect you are converting and the to/from view. 
For example - aView, bView, and cView -

- aView is a subview of bView
- we want to convert aView.frame to cView

If we try to execute the method before bView has been added as a subview of cView, we will get back a bunk response. Unfortunately there is no protection built into the methods for this case. This may seem obvious, but it is something to be aware of in cases where the conversion goes through a long chain of parents.