# Converting two UIViews to the same coordinate system when UIViews are in hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 2 UIImageViews in a ViewController and I'm trying to work out when they intersect.

**imageViewA**: is in my storyboard view, with constraints, and is in a hierarchy of views as follows:

```
- Background
-- Images
--- imageViewA
```

**imageViewB**: is created dynamically and is dragged around the screen using a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

When the drag ends, I want to check if imageViewB intersects with imageViewB. I used the intersects function, but don't get the results I expect, I suppose because imageViewA is in a hierachy of views, which means it's in a different coordinate system. So I want to convert both views to the same coordinate system. How I can do this?

I've tried the following:

```
let frameA = imageViewA.convert(imageViewA.frame, to: self.view)
let frameB = imageViewB.convert(imageViewB.frame, to: self.view)
```

But it doesn't give me the results I expect, which frameB having a much larger Y coordinate.

Do I need to do something like this:

```
let frameA = imageViewA.superview?.superview?.convert(imageViewA.superview?.superview?.frame, to: self.view)
```

There are other questions covering conversion to coordinate systems, but they don't seem to tackle what to do when the view is in a hierarchy.

Comment: hmm the code you show seems like it should work to me :/ this post should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465659/understand-convertrecttoview-convertrectfromview-convertpointtoview-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `imageViewA.frame` is in the geometry (coordinate system) of `imageViewA.superview`, but `UIView.convert(_ rect: to view:)` expects `rect` to be in the geometry of `imageViewA`.

### UPDATE

The simplest solution is to convert `imageViewA.bounds` (which is in `imageViewA`'s geometry) directly to `imageViewB`'s geometry, and then see if it intersects `imageViewB.bounds`, which is also in `imageViewB`'s geometry:

```
let aInB = imageViewA.convert(imageViewA.bounds, to: imageViewB)
if aInB.intersects(imageViewB.bounds) {
    ...
```

### ORIGINAL

<s>The simplest solution</s> is to convert `imageViewA.bounds`, which is in `imageViewA`'s own geometry:

```
let frameA = imageViewA.convert(imageViewA.bounds, to: self.view)
let frameB = imageViewB.convert(imageViewB.bounds, to: self.view)
```

Comment: I have improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the convert function. Just in case it's useful for anyone else, the solution looks like this:

```
let convertedFrameB = frameA.superview?.convert(frameA.frame, from self.view)

if(convertedFrameB.intersects(frameA.frame) {...
   ...
}
```

Here's an extension that might be useful:

```
extension UIView {

func intersectsIgnoringCoordinateSpace(_ view2: UIView) -> Bool {
    let frameOne = self.convert(self.bounds, to: self.topLevelView)
    let frameTwo = view2.convert(self.bounds, to: self.topLevelView)

    return frameOne.intersects(frameTwo)
}

var topLevelView: UIView? {
    get {
        var topView = self.superview

        while(topView?.superview != nil) {
            topView = topView?.superview
        }
        return topView
    }
}
```